# Falha quando faço bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, bundle

Boa tarde, 
Estou com um pequeno problema quando faço `bundle install`:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options
...
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Já tentei fazer `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'`, mas continua-me a dar o mesmo erro.
A versão do ruby que eu tenho é: `ruby 2.1.3p242` e a versão do rails é: `rails 4.2.1`.
Obrigada

Comment: Olá, a resposta resolveu seu problema? Se sim, feche a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gem debugger não é compatível com sua versão de Ruby.

Instale a gem [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) no lugar.

Comment: Obrigada, é isso mesmo.